# Installing PHP on OS X. Syntax errors?

Tags: bash, osx, php

When [installing OS X](http://php-osx.liip.ch/) on Yosemite with `curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6`, I get the following:

```
****
[WARNING]
Detected OS X Yosemite 10.10. As this is quite new, there may be issues still. Your mileage may vary.
****
Get packager.tgz
Unpack packager.tgz
Please type in your password, as we want to install this into /usr/local
Start packager (may take some time)
  File "/usr/local/packager/packager.py", line 38
    print "ERROR: Option %s is not valid for command %s\n" % (opt[0], command)
```

Is this truly a Bash syntax error? It looks like a normal Bash statement to me. What am I missing?

### Update

I tried installing by hand with:

```
curl -s -o /tmp/packager.tgz http://php-osx.liip.ch/packager/packager.tgz
sudo tar -C /usr/local  -xzf /tmp/packager.tgz
sudo /usr/local/packager/packager.py install 5.6-frontenddev
```

and my results were ....

Comment: What's the output of `curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6`, which is the method posted on the site you linked?

Comment: Sorry @eyoung100 -- that is exactly the output

Comment: In that case, try installing by hand.  I'll edit your post with the steps, or see [Install by Hand](http://php-osx.liip.ch/#notes).  Please fill in the update section, and we will go from there.

Comment: @eyoung100 where did you get the information in the edit from?

Comment: @muru, Click Install by Hand in my Comment Above.  I filled out the Update without his results, and am waiting for an edit with his results...

Comment: @eyoung100 It's usually bad practice to fill in your own errors as someone else's, unless you are actually collaborating. I'll skip that edit.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/usr/local/packager/packager.py`?

Comment: @muru I thought we were collaborating.  Your posting of `packager.py` was my next question after his update...

Comment: By the way, OS X comes with PHP installed.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a bash error, but a python error, since the corresponding line in that script is:

```
echo "Start packager (may take some time)";
sudo /usr/local/packager/packager.py install $TYPE-frontenddev
```